# Matching the Scale and Entry in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scale, tkinter-entry

I am going to match an Entry widget with a slider (`Scale`) in the `tkinter`. using the below code, when you change the slider, the Entry widget will change correctly. but, when I change the value in the Entry, it can not be changed, because the value is less than the `from_` value given in the `Scale`. Is there anyone to know how I can solve this problem?

```py
from tkinter import *
win=Tk()
win.geometry('1000x550')

C1 = IntVar()
en1 = Entry(win, textvariable = C1, width=10)
en1.place(x=67, y=60)
sc1 = Scale(win,from_=100, to=530, length=200, variable = C1, resolution = 1, orient = 'horizontal')
sc1.place(x=300, y=40)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use the `bind` option for the widgets you created

Answer (score 1):

I have a little bit of longer approach to this problem but this should work. Basically you bind the `entry` and the `scale` widget with individual methods. You should also use an if statement to change the from_ and to values in the `slide` function so the max and min values of the scale will be changed

So your code should look like this:

```
from tkinter import *

def slide(event):
    num = en1.get() # Get whatever is entered in the entry
    if num.isdigit(): # Checks if it is an integer
        num = int(num) # Convert string to integer
        # Change the values on the scale
        C1.set(num) # Why no if statement?? Automatically snaps to the max or min value
        # Optional at the bottom if you also want the value in the entry changed:
        # on_change(None)

def on_change(event): # Change the value of entry
    en1.delete(0, END)
    en1.insert(0, C1.get())

win=Tk()
win.geometry('1000x550')

C1 = IntVar()
C1.set(250) # Sets the value of the scale
en1 = Entry(win, width=10)
en1.place(x=67, y=60)
en1.insert(0, "250") # Setting the value of the entry
sc1 = Scale(win, from_=100, to=530, length=200, variable = C1, resolution = 1, orient = 'horizontal')
sc1.place(x=300, y=40)

# Use bindings individually
en1.bind("<KeyRelease>", slide) # This sends an event to the slide function whenever you type something in the entry
sc1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_change) # This sends an event to the on_change function whenever you change the value on the scale

win.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I do agree that this solution basically works, but it's always a bad idea to ignore all possible exceptions that could occur. In this case `except ValueError:` would improve this answer.

Comment: You can use `str.isdecimal()` or `str.isdigit()`

Comment: You are right try and except might be a bad idea. I will change my answer now

Comment: There is a `command` option for `Scale` widget and you don't need to use `bind()` on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. There is another problem. When we insert a number in the Entry that is less than the given minimum value or higher than the given maximum value, I need that the value in the Entry automatically changes to the minimum or maximum values and get the bound values. Many thanks if you kindly help me because I am a newcomer to tkinter.

Comment: @acw1668 it doesn't work because you can only slide it once and then it somehow crashes, that's the reason I used bind

Comment: @EmadaldinMohammadiGolafshani , Simple you can just use an if statement: see my updated answer. If this answers your whole question , you can tick this answer now.

This should work:

`if int(num) > sc1['to']: sc1['to'] = int(num)`    ,       

`if int(num) < sc1['from']: sc1['from'] = int(num)`

Comment: It works fine for me when using the `command` option of `Scale` widget.

Comment: well the slider button froze for me. I did what I could

Comment: @ss3387, Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, the updated code does not work correctly. The Entry and Scale have to be completely matched with each other in complying with the minimum and maximum values. In the given code, if you change the value of the Entry to less than the minimum value (for example 20), the minimum value of the Scale can get a value less than the minimum value. In addition, I want to have a default value (for example 250) when open the GUI. Would you please check the code?

Comment: @EmadaldinMohammadiGolafshani Maybe I misunderstood your question, Do you want to change the value in the entry to the minimum if the number entered is lower than the minimum or the value in the entry to be maximum if the number entered is higher than the maximum? Or do you want to change the minimum or maximum value every time you change the entry? Can you please explain a bit more so I exactly know what you want? Like tell me examples of input and what the output is supposed to be.

Comment: @ss3387, Thanks for your response. As you can see in this example the minimum and maximum values are 100 and 530, respectively. When I open the GUI, I want to see the number 250 as the default value for both Scale and Entry. If a user enters 30, I want to have 100 in both Scale and Entry. If he/she inserts 600, I want to see 530 in both Scale and Entry. Many thanks for your response.

Comment: One more question, do you really want the number to become 100 if a user enters 30? I personally think you should only change the value of the scale because the user starts typing in the entry, he types the first digit and see it become 100. In this case he cannot change the value through the entry. So if you agree with me the answer above works now. I don't know what the purpose of this question is. But in my opinion you do not need to snap the value to 100 or 530 if the value entered exceeds the range you want. Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I have added comments to explain the code

Comment: Hopefully your question is answered now